# How to check which component currently has focus

Tags: angular, keyevent, angular7

I am creating a component for sharing key-bindings. Some of these bindings could potentially be used for differing things, depending on the current element in focus. I created a Stackblitz which has the code for the shared component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/keybinding-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

In some cases there will be multiple components in a view, for example a split view using a parent component containing two child components. Is there any way to determine which of these child components (on any element under the child) currently has focus?

Comment: Have you looked into the CDK's [focusMonitor](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#cdkmonitorelementfocus-and-cdkmonitorsubtreefocus)? It sounds like that is what you are looking for.

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to create a custom directive - from it you can read the component's view hierarchy, using `ViewContainerRef`.

Check my answer for a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53070866/3933927